# java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic4, release

Error While running command :
**ionic cordova build android --prod --release**

It perfectly works when I use **ionic cordova run android**

But when I tried to create release apk for deployment it gives an error :

> - What went wrong:  FAILED Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
>
>   > java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2
>   >     aapt2-3.3.0-5013011-windows Daemon #2: Unexpected error during compile
>   >     'E:\Unnati\WorkSpace\gita\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-xxxhdpi\screen.png',
>   >     attempting to stop daemon.   This should not happen under normal
>   >     circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 21s 20 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 19 up-to-date
>   E:\Unnati\WorkSpace\gita\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed
>   with exit code 1 Error output: FAILURE: Build failed with an
>   exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
>
>   > java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2
>   >     aapt2-3.3.0-5013011-windows Daemon #2: Unexpected error during compile
>   >     'E:\Unnati\WorkSpace\gita\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-xxxhdpi\screen.png',
>   >     attempting to stop daemon.   This should not happen under normal
>   >     circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

How to solve this?

Comment: Go to the root of the android project and run `gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace`

Comment: 'gradlew' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. @JensV

Comment: Can you look for a gradlew.bat file in the project? Then open a cmd from there and execute the command

Answer (score 1):

It is solved by adding this in **build.gradle**:

```
allprojects {
    // Workaround for https://issuetracker.google.com/117900475
    // Remove when upgrading to AGP 3.4 or higher.
    configurations.matching { it.name == '_internal_aapt2_binary' }.all { config ->
        config.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            details.useVersion("3.5.0-alpha03-5252756")
        }
    }
}
```